# Xcode: Where to put input file?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to learn C++ and I'm using Xcode.  I have the following `main` method:

```
int main()
{
const int SIZE = 256;
Expression* expression;
char paren, comma, line[SIZE];
ifstream fin("input.txt");
while (true)
{
    symbolTable.init();
    fin.getline(line, SIZE);
    if (!fin)
        break;
    stringstream in(line, ios_base::in);
    in >> paren;
    cout << line << " ";

        expression = SubExpression::parse(in);
        in >> comma;
        parseAssignments(in);
        double result = expression->evaluate();
        cout << "Value = " << result << endl;

    // catch the exceptions


return 0;
}
}
```

Where do I put the file `"input.txt"` so the program can read it?

Comment: What have you tried? Is something not working? Usually, the answer is "In the same directory from which the program is being run"

Comment: On a side note, consistent indentation would make your code more readable.

Comment: @JBentley: No kidding.  That was the formatter here.  It kept telling me "it looks like you have unformatted code" and wouldn't let me post.  This was the best I could get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All relative paths (on OS X, any path that doesn't start with a slash, "/"), are interpreted relative to a process' *working directory*.

If you're running from the terminal, it should be in the terminal's current directory (i.e. `ls` should list it).

If you're running from inside XCode, there is a project setting for which directory should be the working directory.
You set that to wherever your file is, or move the file to wherever that directory is.

Answer (score 2):

The filename parameter of `ifstream` is usually taken as a relative path to the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) so that's where you should put the file.

If you launch the executable from a file manager, the working directory of the process will most likely be set to the directory the executable is in. In that case the text file should be in the same directory.